# EntityManager NullPointerException Spring+Hibernate+Maven

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, maven

This is the thing ... I have my Maven web project based on spring3.0 and i wanted to use hibernate+jpa for my DA ... but when i try to use the entityManager objet i just get a nullPointerException ... here is the code:

```
@Repository
@Component
public class DAOPersonImp implements DAOPerson{

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
@Override
public Person getById(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return entityManager.find(Person.class, id);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public List<Person> getAll() {
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT * FROM  PERSON");
    List<Person> persons = null;
    persons = query.getResultList();
    return persons;
}
```

when i try to create the query objet i get the error.

**This is my applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
```

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PersistUnit" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

**And the error!**

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatchermaven] in context with path [/OneX-1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.divux.onex.daoImp.DAOPersonImp.getAll(DAOPersonImp.java:45)
    at com.divux.onex.logic.FriendListLogic.getEntrys(FriendListLogic.java:23)
    at com.divux.onex.controller.FriendListController.getEntrys(FriendListController.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Dont know how much info whould you need but i will give u guys whatever you need!

Thanks a lot! Srry for my terrible english ...

Comment: Do you have <context:component-scan base-package="com.divux"/> in your applicationContext.xml?

Comment: I'm not much familiar with Hibernate or Spring but while using JSF, `@PersistenceContext` is written with its unit name such as `@PersistenceContext(unitName="yourUnitName")`. It may be an issue, I think.

Comment: how do you call dao.getAll()?

Comment: It looks like you create `DAOPersonImp` directly, but it should be manager by Spring (you don't need `@Component` for it)! In `FriendListLogic` (should be marked as `@Component`) you should have `@Autowired DAOPerson daoPerson;` and in `FriendListController` (should be marked as `@Controller`) you should have `@Autowired FriendListLogic friendListLogic;`.

Comment: @dma_k I just did what u said ... and the error change! now i have problems creating the beans(problems with the autowired it seems) ... sorry about the leng of the error output but ... i dont want to miss any clue.Here is it org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'friendListLogic':Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.divux.onex.daoImp.DAOPersonImp com.divux.onex.logic.FriendListLogic.dao(dont have enough character left for the output

Comment: @Bozho i call it in another class, FriendListLogic with an autowired objet

Comment: @Lion what exactly is the unitName???

Comment: @Alex I have a another xml ... a dispatchermaven-servlet.xml where i define the component-scan, thats why its not showed here!

Comment: Dont know if this is usefull but seems the problem start with the entityManager nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0

Comment: @BrunoX: I think, you miss something in Spring basics, please read [Developing a Spring Framework MVC application step-by-step](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/) if you a re new to Spring. Then read [Classpath scanning and managed components](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning). There might be tons of suggestions but they are all shooting into darkness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PersistenceContex  not injecting entitymanager .So you are getting NullPointerException makesure   persistence.xml in correct place and its unit name is correct .I also post a sample configuration so you can configure applicationContex accordingly.

```
    <!-- Prints used SQL to stdout -->

    <property name="showSql" value="${hibernate.show.sql}"/>

    <!-- Generates tables. -->

    <property name="generateDdl" value="${hibernate.generate.ddl}"/>

    <property name="databasePlatform" value="${postgres.hibernate.database.platform}"/>

</bean>



<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"

      destroy-method="close">

    <property name="driverClass" value="${postgres.datasource.driver.class}"/>

    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${postgres.datasource.jdbc.url}"/>

    <property name="user" value="${postgres.datasource.username}"/>

    <property name="password" value="${postgres.datasourse.password}"/>

    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1"/>

    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1"/>

    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="3"/>

</bean>



<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="postgres.transactionManager"/>



<bean id="postgres.transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">

    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

</bean>



<bean id="entityManagerFactory"

      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter"/>

    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"/>

    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PersistenceUnit"></property>

</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, yeah its seems Im not getting the persistence.xml in the correct directory ... still having problems to find it! but your contribution was completly accurate IMO